# How can OWA running on Exchange 2007 access a mailbox in a store on Exchange 2010?

Tags: exchange-2010

I have just installed a new Exchange 2010 server into our domain, I have 2 Exchange 2007 servers. I've created a user with a mailbox on the Exchange 2010 store, this works fine apart from OWA which is currently pointing to IIS on our Exchange 2007 server, can I allow the OWA running on Exchange 2007 to access the Exchange 2010 store? I know I can point to OWA on the Exchange 2010 server but the problem is our VPN points to the 2007 server and I don't want to switch until all users have been moved across.

Thanks
Scott

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure your 2007 CAS to proxy for the Exchange 2010 CAS, so that it detects where the mailbox is located and sends the user to the correct CAS. Take a look at [this Technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310763.aspx) which explains this in more detail.